# Same app name for iPhone and iPad,but different release dates

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

We are about the release app to the iPad store under the name `appName`. We don't want to add anything to that name (e.g. `HD` ) . the app is now only for iPad(not universal) .

Later we would like to release it to the iPhone under the same name .
But, for this to work we will have to later make that same app to be `universal` , and release an **update** to it.

**Problem:** On the release date to iPhone , we will not get the right attention , because its only an `update`, not a new app. (e.g. get to be in the first places/promption by Apple ,etc ).

How you usually solve this problem ,to get a full attention as a new release, when you only submit an update to include another iDevices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of opinion question rather than a programming one. Still I will let you know my thoughts.

This statement is not entirely true.

***"Problem: On the release date to iPhone , we will not get the right attention , because its only an update, not a new app. (e.g. get to be in the first places/promption by Apple ,etc ).***"

what exactly are you plans for advertising your release or update? If you hope that website that monitor new app releases automatically to advertise your app then yes, you get a shot at the new release and updates not so much.

You can release an iPad version and then with an update make the app universal as long as you advertise your app update like mad all over the social media and such. Hopefully your update will be received with just as interest as your initial app release.

The only other option, which you already know, is to create two different apps with different names "HD" and have two sets of code to maintain which I can tell from experience is a pain in the butt.

If I were you I would hold off on releasing an iPad version till I made it universal. Trust me Apple customers now expect all apps to work on every apple devices and not to buy the same app twice for iPhone vs iPad.

Just my two cents.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. the app is free, but its from the kind of apps that are for big crowed , so we are now thinking of what you just said, although making it iPhone compatible will take much more time now.

Comment: btw if i call it : appName for iPad this is what users will see on their iPad ? or will it cut the words after the name ?

Comment: You can call your app whatever you want when you create it in XCode but if you want to change the display name of what appears once intsalled on the phone then select your target, "Info" tab, and set the "Bundle display name" field to the name you want (i.e. "MySuperApp"). This is the simplest, pain-free solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app same name, but launch the universal version of the app with a different bundle ID.  No problem from the Apple side.